# How to setup PHP to use another mail server?

Tags: php, linux, email

I have a load balancer that also works as a mail server.

I want the clusters to use the load balancers mail server as their default mail system for the PHP `mail()` function

---

### Clusters Settings

#### PHP

The settings on the `php.ini` file look like this:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = mail.email.info
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = me@example.com
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

---

### Load Balancer Settings

#### Postfix

I have added this to the `main.cf`:

```
myhostname = mail.email.info
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.71 192.168.0.*
```

as the clusters are on the `192.168.0.*` subnet.

The mail server on the LB is working perfectly. I am using it for lots of virtual hosts and it is set up on lots of mail software (for example sparrow) So this is not likely to be an issue with it, but more likely to be to do with the permissions of it.

---

When running the PHP script on the cluster:

```
<?php
mail("test@example.com","subject","msg");
?>
```

Nothing is happening. Why?!

---

Please do not be afraid to ask for more info.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573511/how-do-i-specify-to-php-that-mail-should-be-sent-using-an-external-mail-server ?

Comment: As per lxg's comment, mail handling varies by OS and you didn't say what OS you are running on the webserver. (I see the tag but that might refer to the LB)

Comment: @symcbean: As the sendmail path is `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, it's rather unlikely to be a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP documentation, the `smtp_port` and other options are [only used on Windows](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php). Generally, PHP's `mail()` is not really made for using a remote MTA.

I would recommend using a third party library such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Not only can you dispatch your mail to a remote MTA, but you get some valuable extras, too:

- RFC-compliant mails,
- attachments and multipart mails,
- S/MIME support for signing and encrypting e-mails,
- intuitive object-oriented APIs,

and many more.