# Is it possible to integrate sendgrid with built in PHP mail system

Tags: sendgrid

Is it possible to integrate sendgrid with built in PHP mail system so that I only need to change the environment file and sendgrid will automatically know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I'm not a PHP expert, but [the answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573511/how-do-i-specify-to-php-that-mail-should-be-sent-using-an-external-mail-server) suggest that using PHP `mail` to send emails from an external server, like SendGrid, is a bad idea and that there are better libraries available for sending email with SendGrid.

If you want to set up SendGrid to send over SMTP, then the recommendations are [Swift Mailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Check the [documentation on sending with SMTP and SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api) for the settings you will need.

Alternatively, we recommend using the [SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) to send email with the full power of the [SendGrid API](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/mail-send/v3-mail-send).